# Importing JSON into TFDMemTable

Tags: json, delphi

I'm attempting to import JSON from a TMemo to a TFDMemTable.  Upon execution I get a "Exception EAccessViolation..." error. The line of code that appears to be causing the problem is `FDMemTable1.FieldByName('userId').AsString := oProd.GetValue('PutRequest.Item.userId').Value;` which is where I'm appending my first entry to the FDMemTable. I checked the JSON and it appears to be formatted correctly.

Here's my JSON array:

```
{"Jobs":[{"PutRequest":{"Item":{"userId":{"S":"1"},"WorkOrder":{"S":"29236"},"ServiceDate":{"S":"4/12/2019"}}}},{"PutRequest":{"Item":{"userId":{"S":"1"},"WorkOrder":{"S":"29237"},"ServiceDate":{"S":"4/12/2019"}}}}]}
```

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
uses
  System.JSON;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  oJson: TJSONObject;
  oArr: TJsonArray;
  oPair: TJSONPair;
  i: Integer;
  oProd: TJSONObject;
begin
  FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.Add('userId', ftString, 5);
  FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.Add('WorkOrder', ftString, 5);
  FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.Add('ServiceDate', ftString, 10);
  FDMemTable1.Active := True;

  oJson := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Memo1.Lines.Text), 0) as TJSONObject;
  try
    oArr := oJson.Get('Jobs').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
    for i := 0 to oArr.Count - 1 do begin
      oProd := oArr.Items[i] as TJSONObject;
      FDMemTable1.Append;
      FDMemTable1.FieldByName('userId').AsString := oProd.GetValue('PutRequest.Item.userId').Value;
      FDMemTable1.FieldByName('WorkOrder').AsString := oProd.GetValue('PutRequest.Item.WorkOrder').Value;
      FDMemTable1.FieldByName('ServiceDate').AsString := oProd.GetValue('PutRequest.Item.ServiceDate').Value;
      FDMemTable1.Post;
    end;
  finally
    oJson.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I have checked the assignments and values of "oArr" and "oProd" and they appear correct. I'm guessing that I'm not addressing the JSON properly when I'm trying to assign the value to the FDMemTable. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Check if ''userId'' and ''PutRequest.Item.userId'' are returning valid values because for example if "UserId" is not AsString will return nil and thus assigning to it will throw, try this in the debugger by hovering over their properties.

Comment: also try to comment this line and see if the one under it will throw as well

Comment: @Nasreddine Galfout - I added `FDMemTable1.CreateDataSet;` where you suggested and now I get an Access Violation error when I assign the data to the field. I check the values and I'm not getting anything with ''PutRequest.Item.userId" and I even tried `oProd.GetValue('PutRequest').Value;`, but no value either.

Comment: @Nasreddine Galfout - As you suggested I'm not worrying about the assignment to the FDMemTable yet, as I'm just trying to get a key-value pair from the JSON to a ShowMessage statement.  But no luck!

Comment: @Nasreddine Galfout - "ShowMessage('oProd = ' + oProd.ToString);" does show the contents of the JSON array.

Comment: As you can see this becomes a problem of debugging, I would suggest looking into how to use   `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(` and others, for starter you seem to neglect the return value which can be nil and make sure your code matches the structure in your JSON

Comment: @Nasreddine Galfout  - Based on my JSON array provided shouldn't `oProd.GetValue('PutRequest.Item.userId').Value;` give me a value other than nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
`FDMemTable1.CreateDataSet;`
```

under

```
FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.Add('ServiceDate', ftString, 10);
```

which means your dataSet Fields are not created yet and thus the call to

```
FDMemTable1.FieldByName('userId').AsString
```

will return nil and throw an EV when assigning to it

add that line and you are good to go

see [this guide](http://delphi.org/2015/03/firedac-in-memory-dataset-tfdmemtable/) by Jim McKeeth (the code under the video) for proper way to use `TMemTable` and what it can do.

Comment: For 10.3 at least the helps says "Optionally, the dataset can be created setting Active to True."

Comment: @Brian Well I'm on 10.2 and I never dared to try if it works like you say, thanks for the comment though, It means I need to do a quick read up on these again :).